# Determine the total electric power of the circuit with 2 types of voltage?

Tags: voltage, short-circuit, electricity

When 3 lightbulb  have an electric power of 60, 100, 150 respectively V= 220Voltz. Determine the electric power consumed for each lightbulb  that are connected in series when the V=380Votlz

I am really confuse because how I am going to determine the power for each lightbulb when I do not have Resistance neither I (electric current) for the formula P =V*I?

I thought what if I can determine the  I(electric current ) when V=220  and assume I1 == I2 . I am in right path? Sorry I am new to electronics.

Comment: is this a school question?

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. And V=I*R would help you.

Comment: I didn't expect you to do my homework, I just want some explanation in my humble opinion, I was confuse because I didn't know that I could look for resistence in the problem even though it wasn't not mention or consider it. Thanks @BrianCarlton

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the resistance of each based on their rated power and voltage.  P = V^2/R.  e.g. the first one is rated 60W, 220V

Once you know the resistance of each then you can work the resulting series circuit when the 380V is applied across the string.

Then, P = I^2R for each.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWCIc4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYnIOk.png)</sup>

Whereas the current on each lamp in the first diagram is determined by equal voltage in parallel and adds up to the total current, in the second diagram the same current must pass through all three lamps and the voltage is unevenly distributed as a result.

Comment: You are assuming the resistance of each bulb is independent of the current through it which is only true for resistors and not bulb filaments. I will admit that the assumption is necessary to solve the problem given the information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer very informative. The assumption is necesary  I thought that if it wasn't especify I have to find another way.